# rasterio merge giving incorrect result

Tags: python, mosaic, rasterio

I have 4 separate ASCII grids which all contain the same data:

```
1 2 3 4
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 8
7 9 5 4
```

The metadata, however, is different:

```
ncols 4
nrows 4
xllcorner x
yllcorner y
cellsize 1
nodata_value -9999
```

Where `x`  and `y` take on the values (0,0), (4,0), (4,4) and (0,4) repectively. I then Try to run a merge operation as follows using `rasterio`:

```
from rasterio.merge import merge
import rasterio
import glob 

def merge_datasets(out_filename, dataset_list, driver):
    print('running merge command and outputting mosaic')
    mosaic, out_trans = merge(dataset_list)

    print('updating metadata')
    out_meta = dataset_list[0].meta.copy()
    out_meta.update({"driver": driver, "height": mosaic.shape[1], "width": mosaic.shape[2], "transform": out_trans})

    print('writing file')
    with rasterio.open(out_filename, 'w', **out_meta) as dest: # YES, NO, IF_NEEDED, IF_SAFER
    dest.write(mosaic)

    out_dataset = rasterio.open(out_filename)
    return out_dataset

if __name__=='__main__':
    tiles_filename_list = glob.glob(r'test_data/*.asc')
    tiles_dataset_list = open_dataset_list(tiles_filename_list)

    merged_dataset = merge_datasets(r'test_data/out.asc', tiles_dataset_list, driver='AAIGrid')
```

This creates the following incorrect grid:

```
ncols        8
nrows        8
xllcorner    0.000000000000
yllcorner    0.000000000000
cellsize     1.000000000000
NODATA_value -9999
 1 2 3 4 1 2 2 3
 3 4 5 6 3 4 4 5
 3 4 5 6 3 4 4 5
 4 5 6 8 4 5 5 6
 1 2 3 4 1 2 2 3
 3 4 5 6 3 4 4 5
 4 5 6 8 4 5 5 6
 7 9 5 4 7 9 9 5
```

Does anyone know why this occurs. I would have expected:

```
ncols        8
nrows        8
xllcorner    0.000000000000
yllcorner    0.000000000000
cellsize     1.000000000000
NODATA_value -9999
 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6
 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6
 4 5 6 8 4 5 6 8
 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6
 4 5 6 8 4 5 6 8
 7 9 5 4 7 9 5 4
```

I tried looking into the different options in the [merge method in rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.merge.html) but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realized that adding the argument `precision=50` to the merge call solves the problem. I don't fully understand why, though.

Comment: I have recently come across the same problem (but merging tif tiles that amount to billions of raster cells), and 'precision=50' seems to do the job. Have you actually found out what it exactly means and why it fixes it?
(Thanks for tip!)

Comment: Not really, but I logged an issue in https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/1837 I think there was a pull request which increased the default precision so in theory the head revision of rasterio should not exhibit this behavior anymore. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. I just fail to see why the number of decimal points of precision would affect in such a way the merged raster (basically, the values of a big percentage of cells get shifted one position to the right, as in your example). Out of my understanding.

Comment: I can confirm I am still encountering this issue as of rasterio 1.1.5, which a number of cells get shifted one position to the right.